# Two-column responsive blog layout with CSS grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I need the following responsive design, which I would like to achieve with pure CSS:

[image]

I have tried the following CSS grid approach, but it ends up stretching the `Heading` box to the height of the `Table of contents`. Is there any way to have those row heights be independent of one another?

```css
h1          { grid-area: heading; }
div.toc     { grid-area: toc; }
div.content { grid-area: content; }
div.author  { grid-area: author; }
div.related { grid-area: related; }

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "heading"
    "toc"
    "content"
    "author"
    "related";
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  article {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "heading toc"
      "content author"
      "related .";
  }
}

article > * { border: 1px solid red; }
article > *, h3, p, ul, li { margin: 8px; }
```

```html
<article>    
  <h1>My Heading</h1>
  <div class="toc">
    <h3>Table of contents</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Chapter 1</li>
      <li>Chapter 2</li>
      <li>Chapter 3</li>
      <li>Chapter 4</li>
      <li>Chapter 5</li>
      <li>Chapter 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere quidem modi, exercitationem atque cumque rem molestias dicta delectus tempore fuga voluptatum deserunt, quasi aliquid nulla dignissimos praesentium ullam, numquam nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut ab ipsa, fugit aliquam cumque quisquam, inventore mollitia perferendis, tempora nam magni maiores ea eveniet qui minus voluptatum doloribus modi quam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ut nulla. Cupiditate numquam dolor cumque, iure, debitis nulla reprehenderit placeat alias temporibus, maiores porro, repudiandae accusamus optio dicta quos officiis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum ea voluptatum, nam. Exercitationem eligendi magni doloremque, rerum aspernatur eos consequuntur, est vero facere nam temporibus libero animi modi cumque eveniet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima veniam ipsum, ullam enim quisquam maiores illo totam consectetur dolor in laboriosam animi quam laborum quas quibusdam tempore, excepturi magni rerum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus minus excepturi temporibus velit laboriosam, nemo architecto repudiandae maiores, quidem mollitia recusandae corporis officiis deserunt quas, quis at, aliquid a animi!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="author">- written by me</div>
  <div class="related">
    <h3>Related articles</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Article 1</li>
      <li>Article 2</li>
      <li>Article 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good old floats ??

```css
h1          { grid-area: heading; overflow:hidden; }
div.toc     { grid-area: toc; }
div.content { grid-area: content; overflow:hidden; }
div.author  { grid-area: author; }
div.related { grid-area: related; overflow:hidden; }

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "heading"
    "toc"
    "content"
    "author"
    "related";
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  article {
   display: block;
  }
  h1,
  div.content,
  div.related {
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 18px);
    clear:left;
  }
  div.toc,
  div.author {
    float:right;
    width: calc(50% - 18px);
    overflow:hidden;
  }
}

article > * { border: 1px solid red; }
article > *, h3, p, ul, li { margin: 8px; }
```

```html
<article>    
  <div class="toc">
    <h3>Table of contents</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Chapter 1</li>
      <li>Chapter 2</li>
      <li>Chapter 3</li>
      <li>Chapter 4</li>
      <li>Chapter 5</li>
      <li>Chapter 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1>My Heading</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere quidem modi, exercitationem atque cumque rem molestias dicta delectus tempore fuga voluptatum deserunt, quasi aliquid nulla dignissimos praesentium ullam, numquam nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut ab ipsa, fugit aliquam cumque quisquam, inventore mollitia perferendis, tempora nam magni maiores ea eveniet qui minus voluptatum doloribus modi quam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, ut nulla. Cupiditate numquam dolor cumque, iure, debitis nulla reprehenderit placeat alias temporibus, maiores porro, repudiandae accusamus optio dicta quos officiis.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum ea voluptatum, nam. Exercitationem eligendi magni doloremque, rerum aspernatur eos consequuntur, est vero facere nam temporibus libero animi modi cumque eveniet.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima veniam ipsum, ullam enim quisquam maiores illo totam consectetur dolor in laboriosam animi quam laborum quas quibusdam tempore, excepturi magni rerum!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus minus excepturi temporibus velit laboriosam, nemo architecto repudiandae maiores, quidem mollitia recusandae corporis officiis deserunt quas, quis at, aliquid a animi!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="author">- written by me</div>
  <div class="related">
    <h3>Related articles</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Article 1</li>
      <li>Article 2</li>
      <li>Article 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Oh wow this is quite brilliant!